# How to import pictures using DXL script into rational doors module

Tags: ole, ibm-doors

I tried importing a picture using dxl script as given in DXL reference manual, but my attempts are in vain. It results in an error:

```
-R-E- DXL: <Line:1> The format of this picture is not recognised

-I- DXL: execution halted
```

Note: The format of the picture is a BMP image.

My code is:

```
if (importPicture("test", "C:\\Users\\Downloads\\test1.bmp", "BMP")) {
print "Successfully imported picture
test.bmp\n"
} else {
print "Failed to import picture test.bmp\n"
}
```

I want to import around 250 images into rational DOORS module.
What would be the better way please ?

All images are placed on the same path. Images are named like

```
test1,

test2,

test3,

....

test250.
```

This images will be placed in a module as a OLE Objects by replacing a specific text object like

```
Figure1,

Figure2,

Figure3,

....

Figure250.
```

How could I automate this task using DXL Script?

Answer (score 0):

I did not test it and I don't know if it helps, but it seems the perm “importPicture” is not maintained any more. Perhaps you have better results with the perm “insertPictureFile”? Also, you can try “bool pictureCompatible(string filename, int format)”. If the pictures are not compatible, they might have to be reduced to less colors(?!)

Comment: Mike, "insertPictureFile" did not help. Results in an error "\Downloads\test.bmp' does not exist
"

Comment: I am very sorry for replying so late. Unfortunately there is still no email sent out in stackoverflow when a comment is posted. So, I have a DOORS installation at hand now and used the following command 

insertPictureFileAfter ("C:\\Program Files\\IBM\\Rational\\DOORS\\9.7\\lib\\dxl\\standard\\changemgnt\\about\\about.bmp", formatBMP, current)

(note the double backslashes.) This works like a charm.

Comment: Hello @Mike Apologies if find my question not helpful. But I am really struggling with this. Is there any way how to import image present inside excel file to Doors using DXL.. I tried many properties like oleGet(objSheet, "Pictures", objpic) or with " Shapes", "TopLeftCell".. But I couldn't even get if an image exists in cell or not. Could you please help me if you know? I am totally going mad working for this since a week